# Regex for string containing anything other than [A-Z][a-z][0-9][\s][-]

Tags: java, regex, string

Currently i have

```
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9]");
            boolean invalidChar = p.matcher("text").find();
```

To find invalid char if they are anything other than alphabets and digit, but i also want to add a whitespace and a hyphen as valid character. Whitespace and hypen can appear anywhere in the string

Comment: can't you just add `\s-` to the regex?

Comment: Why don't you check if the string contains **only** what you want and negate the result, like: `!asin.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9\\- ]+")`?

Comment: Try `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]`

Comment: how about a hyphen? such as -

Comment: [^a-zA-Z0-9\s-] works and now if i want to limit the whitespace to be just one consecutive? like "saad -h sk" is valid but "saad<threespaces>-h sk" is not

Comment: @Saad what do you mean by that? You only want to match whitespace if there's only a single one? What about newline+tab?

Comment: just multiple whitespaces consecutively shouldnt be valid, but single whitespace can occur many times in the string.

Comment: @Saad yes, but what about `\n\t` is that valid? When you say multiple whitespaces are you referring to **all** whitespace characters or just the space character?

Comment: lets make them valid.

Comment: That looks like [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Tell us what you really want to do, otherwise your question will evolve into new one with each answer/suggestion.

Comment: What about `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]| {2,}`?

Comment: ctwheels exactly what i wanted! thanks a lot man

Comment: @Saad I posted it as an answer with a slight enhancement for speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to additional specifications below the question (in comments), the OP is looking to match anything that is not an alphanumeric character, hyphen, or whitespace, with the exception of multiple spaces. For those specs, the following regex can be used:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+| {2,}
```

- `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+` Match one or more of any character that is not in the set
- `{2,}` Match the space character 2 or more times

To only match two or more hyphens, you can use `[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+| {2,}|-{2,}`

If you're looking to keep a single space character (and get rid of spaces that follow), you can use the following. The second regex adds the same functionality for hyphens:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+|(?<= ) +
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+|(?<= ) +|(?<=-)-+
```

Comment: So if i want to make that {2,} apply for both white space and -. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your question almost answers itself? Or are you looking for the java code to do what you want?

Are you really wanting to allow any whitespace /s character such as spaces, tabs, or linebreaks? Or do you only want to allow spaces?

Here's a single character that is anything that is not a letter, number, space, or hyphen:
`[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]`

Here's a string of characters that meet the above requirements:
`[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]+`

Here's an easy site to test things out in regex: https://regexr.com/